# Access current package's label in BUILD

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to obtain the current package's label in the BUILD file?

Imagine I have some rule invocation like this:

```
do_x_or_fail(
    name = "foo",
    <...>
    message_on_error = "Incorrect BarBaz setup for " + ?CURRENT_PACKAGE? + ". Check Xyz."
)
```

How would I implement `?CURRENT_PACKAGE?`?

I see there are functions like `Label()` or `native.package_relative_label()`, but I didn't manage to call them from the `BUILD` file directly.

I tried calling `native.package_relative_label()` from a `BUILD` file. It failed with the following error: `name 'native' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BUILD` files can invoke `package_name()`.